# In KeystoneJS, how can I make all values initially selected in a Relationship field using many: true?

Tags: keystonejs

I am using KeystoneJS. I have a relationship field in my Post model that references another model called Device. I am using many: true to allow users to select multiple items from the Device model.

Is there a way to have them all initially selected when creating a Post?

Right now my relationship field looks like this:

```
availableDevices: {
  type: Types.Relationship,
  ref: 'Device',
  many: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In  your model definition, you can add pre-processing steps to populate fields that you'd like to have a default value in the relationship. I haven't done this with a `many` relationship, but I have done it with a relationship like this:

```
Report.schema.pre('save', function (next) {
        this.wasNew = this.isNew;
        if (!this.employee) {
                this.employee = this.createdBy;
        }
        if (!this.timeEnteredTheHomeStr) {
                if(!this.timeEnteredTheHome) {
                        this.timeEnteredTheHome = Date.now
                }
                this.timeEnteredTheHomeStr = String(this.timeEnteredTheHome);
        }
        next();
});
```

When someone creates a new report object, the `employee` field is automatically set to the user object referenced in the `createdBy` field.

Comment: This is not a complete answer to you question, but it's a good place to start looking.